# Problem of making maze game that is gyroscope control in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title, I'm making a maze game that enables players can control the maze by the mobile gyroscope, I didn't have this problem on the iOS platform. When the platform change to Android, the Input.gyro.attitude always is (x, y, z, -0.6), I need to rotate my phone 90 degrees to make the attitude become (x, y, z, -1), and that is what I want. How can I make sure whatever player's phone points in which direction at the start, the attitude always is (x, y, z, -1)?

I can set the gyro.enable = false to reset the gyro, but Android cannot

Here is the video of the problem, please take a look at my problems.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sed6qqFVFUbg4TJXqfM6GviVFnySa-tQ/view?usp=sharing

(Sorry for my worst grammar and English)

This is how I get the gyroscope from the mobile and rotate the maze

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GyroManager : Singleton<GyroManager>
{
    [Header("Gryo")]
    [SerializeField] private Gyroscope gyro;
    [SerializeField] private Quaternion phoneQuaternion;
    [SerializeField] private float hardFixedZ;
    public bool gyroActive;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (gyroActive && GameController.Instance.isGameStart)
        {
            phoneQuaternion =  GyroToUnity(gyro.attitude);
        }
    }
    public void EnableGyro()
    {
        //reture if Gyro already active
        if (gyroActive)
            return;

        //Check whether or not users' phone hasn't garrow's scope in it
        if (SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope)
        {
            Debug.Log("Gyro is support on this device");
            gyro = Input.gyro;
            gyro.enabled = true;
            gyroActive = gyro.enabled;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Gyro is not support on this device");
        }

    }

    public Quaternion GetPhoneGyro()
    {
        return phoneQuaternion;
    }

    public Quaternion GyroToUnity(Quaternion q)
    {
        return new Quaternion(q.x, 0, q.y, -q.w);
    }

    protected void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.skin.label.fontSize = Screen.width / 20;

        if (gyroActive)
        {
            GUILayout.Label("Orientation: " + Screen.orientation);
            GUILayout.Label("input.gyro.attitude: " + phoneQuaternion);
            GUILayout.Label("iphone width/height/font: " + Screen.width + " : " + Screen.height + " : "+ GUI.skin.label.fontSize);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowGyro : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (GyroManager.Instance.gyroActive)
        {
            transform.rotation = GyroManager.Instance.GetPhoneGyro();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the gyro is out by 0.4 why not just adjust it for android build?

Comment: I’m not sure what is the adjustment if the android build, I had already tried to change the screen orientation in game, but it didn’t help. Also I had try to hard fix the gyro to make the gyro.attitude.w keep to 1, it didn’t work. Because although I hard fixed it, the other value of gyro.attitude (x, y, z) is the value of value when gyro.attitude.w is 0.6 (which is pointing my forward).